# JSON encode without quotes

Tags: php, json

This is how my array looks like

```
$a = array( 'a' => 'apple' , 'b' => 'banana' );
```

This is the output after I run the `json_encode`

```
{"a":"apple","b":"banana"}
```

Now, I want the output should be in the following format - remove the quotes around keys and replace the double quotes around values with single quotes

```
{a:'apple',b:'banana'}
```

Can someone tell me how to do this ?

Comment: Why do you want that? It isn't valid JSON, so no-one else will be able to parse it afterwards.

Comment: It seems like you want to do something with your JSON (maybe display some data?), but don't know how. If you describe what it is you're trying to achieve and why you feel you need this without quotes, maybe we can suggest a proper solution.

Comment: The features that you are looking for can be found in [JSON5](https://json5.org/). That format is not an international standard, so don’t expect it to work everywhere without explicit library support. There are [PHP libraries](https://github.com/kujirahand/JSON5-PHP)  for it, too, although I can’t vouch for any.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution:

```
$a = array( 'a' => 'apple' , 'b' => 'banana' );

$res = '';

foreach ($a as $key => $value){;
    $res .= "{$key}:'{$value}',";
}

$res = rtrim($res, ',');
$res = sprintf("%s%s%s","{", $res, "}");

echo($res);
```

Comment: What if $key or $value contains a single quote mark (`'`)? What if the input is a list of objects? etc. This might work for the specific, trivial example in the question, but it certainly wouldn't serve as a general encoding algorithm. So I'd question its real value. And those algorithms already exist anyway - see the link that Chris Haas posted above.

Comment: In fact it is a trivial solution and not enough global, a library might be the solution but it is a little heavy for his request.

Comment: Realistically though, you think he really only wants this single output from this single piece of input data? In reality it's going to be just an example of the overall idea - it's clearly not even real data. They will want it to work on any input coming from their application or database. So I would be thinking that to be genuinely useful, a solution needs to fully replace all the things that json_encode can do, except it should produce the output in the non-standard format requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **preg_replace**

```
$a = array( 'a' => 'apple' , 'b' => 'banana' , 'c' => 'orange' );
$a = json_encode($a);

$yourJSON = own_format($a);

print_r($yourJSON); 
//{a:'apple',b:'banana'}

function own_format($jsonData){
    
    $pattern = array('/{"/i','/":/i','/,"/i');

    $preg = preg_replace($pattern[0], "{", $jsonData);
    $preg = preg_replace($pattern[1], ":", $preg);
    $preg = preg_replace($pattern[2], ",", $preg);
    
    $Output = str_replace('"',"'",$preg);
    
    return $Output;
}
```

Comment: This screws up if the original text contains quote marks (either single or double): http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/851ef975e899edb9db3cdd92dcf37800d6846893 . There may be other problems too, potentially, but that's one I've tested. Chris Haas provided links in the comments to PHP libraries which can already do this task successfully, in any case.